# Android id fetching problem

Tags: android

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {

```
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) 

            {

                String name;
                name=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                String[] projection1 = new String[]{
                        People._ID
                     };

                Cursor pCur=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection1,People._ID+"="+name,null,null);

                pCur.moveToFirst();
                if(pCur.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String id;
                    int x=0;
                    do
                    {
                        id=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"resule::"+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        x++;

                    }while(pCur.moveToNext());
                }

            }


            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {

                // DO Nothing
            }

        });
```

I am novice in android development.spinner has all contact name i want get id from particular name.please help me.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Arpit Trivedi

Comment: Get particular id from the spinner list?

Comment: Thanks nikola if i want contact number from name that is selected by spinner how can i do that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get particular id from the list than you should populate the spinner outside the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` because you do it when the item is clicked. All you do to get the item data is `name=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);` like you did at the beginning. Just populate the spinner outside this method, let say at point after you fetch the contacts. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method with a name.You will get the id

```
public long idForName(String name){

    int count=spinner.getCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    if(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(name)) return spinner.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
    }
```